# What is the best tool to mock all AWS services using python3 and pytest

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, pytest

I need to mock all AWS services(For example: EC2, S3, Redshift, Lambda, Dynamodb etc) in python. 
I am using pytest framework for writing test cases and I found "pytest-localstack" plugin for mocking AWS services.
But also I found few more tools like moto, localstack. 
Also i know that boto3 can be used to interact with AWS cloud.

I am feeling "pytest-localstack" is best for my requirement but please provide your suggestion whether i can go ahead with it or i need use other tools.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7):

There are two well known Python mocking libraries

https://github.com/spulec/moto and https://github.com/garnaat/placebo

Comment: Sebastien: Can you please shed light over the differences between `moto` and `local stack`?

Comment: This article explains the differences and talk about other solutions https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/mocking-aws-services-amol-kokje/